# PHP allow Symbol # when $_GET action

Tags: php, anchor

How to set `$_GET` allow this Symbol `#`

Example :

```
$a = "NE-TH#1-8";

<a href="test.php?a=<?php echo $a; ?>"Test</a>
```

When I try to click that link and echo that variable, it will just show `NE-TH`. It should be `NE-TH#1-8`

Please help

Comment: Use `<?php echo urlencode($a); ?>` instead.

Comment: @AmalMurali Still same, the result is just NE-TH

Comment: Probably because of the missing `>` before `Test`. Try this: `<a href="test.php?a=<?php echo $a; ?>">Test</a>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) it (because # signifies a document fragment in a url, which browsers don't send with HTTP requests).

```
<?php $a = "NE-TH#1-8"; ?>
<a href="test.php?a=<?= urlencode( $a ) ?>">Test</a>
```